# Sharing interactive models in multiple bokeh plots

Tags: python, bokeh

I am just starting with bokeh, and I would like to represent 3 datasets on 3 different plots, in a grid, such that all of them have some toggleable vertical lines. For example

```
x = np.arange(50)
data = np.random.rand(3, x.shape[0]) * [[0.1], [1], [100]]  # Different scales

tags = [1, 17, 31]
colors = 'red green red'.split()

ax = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
bx = figure(x_range=ax.x_range, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
cx = figure(x_range=ax.x_range, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)

for t, c in zip(tags, colors):
    ax.add_layout(Span(location=t, dimension='height', line_color=c))
    bx.add_layout(Span(location=t, dimension='height', line_color=c))
    cx.add_layout(Span(location=t, dimension='height', line_color=c))

ax.line(x, data[0])
bx.line(x, data[1])
cx.line(x, data[2])

p = gridplot([[ax, bx, cx]])
show(p)
```

Beside the fact that I would like to add the `Span` elements to be part of a single axis and make it shared, instead of adding them to each plot, I would like to create a legend for the `Span` objects and make them toggleable by color.

So, in this case, I would have a single legend that is shared in all 3 plots, and in this legend I would have 2 entries, one for red lines and one for green lines. Clicking one color would hide all the lines of that color on all the plots.

How can I do this?

Comment: Found a suggestion for a similar issue on github: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Span doesn't have legend property, you need to create two dummy lines to show the legend. In the following example, I use `tags` property to keep the `Span` objects to show/hide.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import Span, CustomJS
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show

x = np.arange(50)
data = np.random.rand(3, x.shape[0]) * [[0.1], [1], [100]]  # Different scales

tags = [1, 17, 31]
colors = 'red green red'.split()

ax = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
bx = figure(x_range=ax.x_range, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
cx = figure(x_range=ax.x_range, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)

spans = {"red":[], "green":[]}

for t, c in zip(tags, colors):
    span1 = Span(location=t, dimension='height', line_color=c)
    span2 = Span(location=t, dimension='height', line_color=c)
    span3 = Span(location=t, dimension='height', line_color=c)
    ax.add_layout(span1)
    bx.add_layout(span2)
    cx.add_layout(span3)
    spans[c].extend([span1, span2, span3])

ax.line(x, data[0])
bx.line(x, data[1])
cx.line(x, data[2])

p = gridplot([[ax, bx, cx]])

red_line = ax.line([0], [0], legend="red", color="red")
green_line = ax.line([0], [0], legend="green", color="green")

ax.legend.location = "top_left"
ax.legend.click_policy="hide"

red_line.tags = spans["red"]
green_line.tags = spans["green"]

def toggle_visible(p=p):
    for line in cb_obj.tags:
        line.visible = cb_obj.visible

callback = CustomJS.from_py_func(toggle_visible)
for line in (red_line, green_line):
    line.js_on_change("visible", callback)

show(p)
```